# Entity not updating unless I stop/start debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have an DbSet entity `db.Payscales`

There's a page on my site where you are able to update the pay-scales, and there is a page where you select the pay-scales from a dropdown menu.

Updating the pay-scales works perfectly, and will even change the values in the database. However, on the dropdown, the values do not update. It retains the last value "known" when the project was built.

The only way to fix this, is to stop debugging and start the site again (essentially rebuilding), and start it again. The values display correctly on the dropdown after this.

I apologize if i'm not being thorough enough, but this seems to be more a general question about entities rather than a question with the code itself.

Just to be safe, here is the code for the dropdown menu:

**DropDownValues.cs**

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetPayScaleList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "", Value = "" });
    foreach (var temp in db.PayScales)
    {
        ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Salary + "|" + temp.BaseGross, Value = temp.Salary.ToString() });
    }
    return ls;
}
```

and the code for the actual dropdown menu itself:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.teacher.SalaryCode , TeachersProj.Models.DropDropValues.GetPayScaleList())
```

Edit:

Since requested, here is the update method as well!

**PayScalesController.cs**

```
//
// POST: /PayScales/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PayScale payscale)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Entry(payscale).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(payscale);
}
```

Comment: Does refreshing the page (F5) or doing a hard-refresh (Ctrl-F5) get you the new values?

Comment: ofcourse it won't update cuz you never use JavaScript to update it

Comment: @Steve i'm not entirely sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @NillBye you need to read up on how HTML works. razor is a server engine and it only generates the html once. After it got sent to the user razor controls nothing of it.

Comment: @Steve I only want the dropdown to be generated once. The issue is the entity the dropdown is taking from isn't updating properly when it generates.

Comment: check your database directly and see if the changes are made. If it is then your select logic is wrong. if not then your update needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the entity WAS updating, for some reason it takes over an hour to update.

When stopping and rebuilding, that forced some action to go through and that's why it was updating. But i took a break and came back later, and it was updated without my doing.

Comment: You might want to look into that.  That is not normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you just need to refresh your page after the database update.  Since you are using the `@Html` directive (I assume this is an MVC project based on this) to get your dropdown list, the contents of the list are defined when the page is loaded.  Updating the database will not reflect in the UI until you reload the page.

If you want to dynamically update your dropdown list without a page reload, you will need to implement some sort of Ajax polling that calls `GetPayScaleList()` and sets the dropdown list contents or implement some sort of SignalR push-style update (likely overkill).

Edit:

Try this for your update logic:

```
public ActionResult Edit(PayScale payscale)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existingEntry = db.Find(payscale);
        if(existingEntry != null)
        {
             db.Entry(existingEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(payscale);
             db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
             //Handle updating a missing record how you want
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(payscale);
}
```

Comment: Refreshing (including a hard refresh) doesn't seem to do the trick.

I added a breakpoint on the list, and went through each line, and right in the foreach `db.PayScales` still pulls the old value, even though when I add a breakpoint to the update code `db.PayScales` has the correct value..

Comment: Please share your update method.  It sounds like maybe you're not calling `context.SaveChanges()` or something.

Comment: I've edited my OP. The only thing I can think of at this point is the list is static, and thus can't update...?

However from my understanding, the list has to be static for it to be input in a dropdown menu, otherwise you get a "object reference is required for non-static field"

Truth be told, I don't know *too* much about C#, i'm just fixing a program and running from there...

Comment: @NillBye I think your update logic wasn't quite there.  I updated my answer.  You obviously may want to handle failures differently than I have.  Hope that works!